# Swift call timer from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TimerManager class that I would like to access in multiple `ViewControllers` but I can't figure out a good way to do it. My code is as follows:

```
class TimerManager {

    private var timer: NSTimer
    private var timeRemaining: Int

    init(initialTime: Int) {
        self.timer = NSTimer()
        self.timeRemaining = initialTime
    }

    func startTimer() {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerManager.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func endTimer() {
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }

    func getTimeRemaining() -> Int {
        return self.timeRemaining
    }

    @objc func update() {
        if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
            self.timeRemaining = self.timeRemaining - 1
        }
        else {
            endTimer()
        }
    } 
}
```

In my `ViewController` I would like to be able to access my `update()` function to update a timer (which is a `UILabel`) on my actual page, but since my `startTimer()` function calls it every second, I don't know how to access `update()` every time it is called. I briefly looked into `protocols` but I'm not really sure how they work or if that would be useful in my case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at implementing a singleton class - here's one tutorial: http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Answer (score 1):

As @sschale suggested, you can do this by using a singleton to ensure that you will be accessing the same instance anywhere in your code. To do this, you need to set the init to private and provide a static member variable to access your single instance.

```
class TimerManager 
{
    static let sharedInstance = TimerManager()

    private var timer: NSTimer
    private var timeRemaining: Int

    private init()
    {
        let initialTime = 1
        self.timer = NSTimer()
        self.timeRemaining = initialTime
    }
    private init(initialTime: Int) 
    {
        self.timer = NSTimer()
        self.timeRemaining = initialTime
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in your ViewControllers you can just call it like this:

```
TimerManager.sharedInstance.startTimer()
```

Comment: So I'm not really concerned with calling my `startTimer()` method as much as I am with the `update()` method. I need to be able to set the `UILabel` somehow using that method. If I just call `startTimer()` then there is no way to update my label text. So what I need is to be able to override `update()` but I don't think there is an option to do that in swift

Answer (score 0):

```
class TimerManager {

    private var timer: NSTimer
    private var timeRemaining: Int
    private var intervalBlock: (TimerManager -> ())?

    init(initialTime: Int) {
        self.timer = NSTimer()
        self.timeRemaining = initialTime
    }

    func startTimer(intervalBlock: (TimerManager -> ())? = nil) {
        self.intervalBlock = self
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerManager.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func endTimer() {
        self.intervalBlock = nil
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }

    func getTimeRemaining() -> Int {
        return self.timeRemaining
    }

    @objc func update() {
        if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
            self.timeRemaining = self.timeRemaining - 1
            intervalBlock()
        }
        else {
            intervalBlock()
            endTimer()
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the best implementations of Timer on the background queue I found from this [article](https://medium.com/over-engineering/a-background-repeating-timer-in-swift-412cecfd2ef9)

```
class RepeatingTimer {

    let timeInterval: TimeInterval

    init(timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        self.timeInterval = timeInterval
    }

    private lazy var timer: DispatchSourceTimer = {
        let t = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
        t.schedule(deadline: .now() + self.timeInterval, repeating: self.timeInterval)
        t.setEventHandler(handler: { [weak self] in
            self?.eventHandler?()
        })
        return t
    }()

    var eventHandler: (() -> Void)?

    private enum State {
        case suspended
        case resumed
    }

    private var state: State = .suspended

    deinit {
        timer.setEventHandler {}
        timer.cancel()
        resume()
        eventHandler = nil
    }

    func resume() {
        if state == .resumed {
            return
        }
        state = .resumed
        timer.resume()
    }

    func suspend() {
        if state == .suspended {
            return
        }
        state = .suspended
        timer.suspend()
    }
}
```

Usage: -

In any of your ViewControllers

For example: -

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
 var timer: RepeatingTimer!

// MARK: - ViewController LifeCycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     timer =  RepeatingTimer(timeInterval: 1)
        timer.eventHandler = {
            print("Timer called")
        }

}
```